# Can I INSERT only when a record doesn't exist in a single statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to insert values into a table with these columns: `Id` `MasterId` `ZipCode` `Locality` `Value`, `CreatedTime`, `UpdatedTime`

A unique value is defined by these 3 columns: `MasterId` `ZipCode` `Locality`

There is no unique constraint on the database across these columns, but I need to make sure that 2 users can't enter the same data. I am unable to make changes to the T-SQL Database schema.

Current SQL:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Carrier VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, GETDATE(), GETDATE())
```

My SQL changes:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM dbo.Carrier
    WHERE MasterId = ?
    AND ZipCode = ?
    AND Locality = ?
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Carrier VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, GETDATE(), GETDATE())
END
```

These changes work for standard user input, but there is also a service that inserts many entries at the same time. Sometimes this service will try to insert thousands of the same unique rows in a multi-threaded fashion and the SQL has a race condition, because it is not one statement. This allows duplicates to be entered when 2 statements are executing simultaneously.

Is there a way to insert only when a record doesn't exist in a single statement?

I don't have this problem on UPDATE, because I can do a where `UpdatedTime` hasn't changed.

Comment: Merge statement https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: The `top 1` should be utterly redundant with an `exists` clause, perhaps causing a few extra nano-seconds of effort for parsing the query.

Comment: Actually, it's not guaranteed for it to work with standard user input either, it's just much harder to hit the race condition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks I didn't know that.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yeah I know it is possible, just unlikely.

Comment: You want not a "single statement". You want to avoid the race condition. Race condition is still there even if you use a single `INSERT` with a `NOT EXISTS` sub-query, or `MERGE`. **Unless** you specify proper locking hints. See details for [`INSERT`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx) and for [`MERGE`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

I would do this as a single statement using `not exists`:

```
insert into dbo.Carrier (masterid, zipcode, locality, . . . )
    select v.*
    from (values (?, ?, ?, ... ), (?, ?, ?, ...)) v(masterid, zipcode, locality, . . .)
    where not exists (select 1
                      from dbo.Carrier c
                      where c.masterid = v.masterid and c.zipcode = v.zipcode and c.locality = v.locality
                     );
```

EDIT:

If you want to protect the database for race conditions, you should have the database do the protection.  Add a unique index/constraint on `(masterid, zipcode, locality)`.  Then you should just ignore any error that violates the constraint.

Comment: ...what I would try too, although you should probably list the required transaction level, too.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the main problem of the question - the race condition. Yes, you wrote a single `INSERT` statement, but it is as prone to the race condition as two separate statements. One way to fix it would be wrapping it into transaction and use `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` hints for the inner `SELECT`. See http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx for details.

Comment: Yeah I tried this approach and can confirm that this alone doesn't help defeat the race condition.

Answer (score 1):

A [MERGE statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.110).aspx) solution would be something like this:

```
MERGE INTO Carrier dst
USING (VALUES(?,?,?,...)) as src(MasterId, Zipcode, Locality,...)
ON src.MasterId=dst.MasterId AND src.Zipcode=dst.Zipcode AND src.Locality=dst.Locality
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
    MasterId, Zipcode, Locality
    , ...
) VALUES (
    src.MasterId, src.Zipcode, src.Locality
    , ...
)
```

If desired you could also have the merge statement do an UPDATE on matching rows at the same time as it inserts missing rows.

Comment: `MERGE` doesn't magically take care of the atomicity either (Essentially, it still runs separate statements, so you'd still have concurrency issues.  Also, the point was to make sure there was no new row with a matching key, so I doubt blindly updating an existing row is going to help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE and a Join:

```
;with new_record as (
    select 1 as MasterId , 90065 as ZipCode, 1 as Locality
)
insert into Carrier(MasterId, ZipCode, Locality)
select a.MasterId, a.ZipCode, a.Locality
from new_record a
left join Carrier b
on a.MasterId = b.MasterId
    and a.ZipCode = b.ZipCode
    and a.Locality = b.Locality
where b.MasterId is null
```

Comment: Technically still doesn't avoid the race condition, which is the real problem.